# Creating a Unix socket based authentication server for dovecot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl, dovecot

I am in the process of building a custom authentication for email accounts. The imap/pop3 server is dovecot. The dovecout have an easy option to use  Key-value authentication (dict) database via socket.  The have the documentation  and perl socket server example in https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/dict/

I need a socket server in python to  enable authentication via socket  url

```
uri = proxy:/var/run/auth_proxy_dovecot/socket:somewhere
```

What inputs are need to send the socket?
What is the format of the input ?
What are the output format expected ?

I was unable to find any such developer documentations regarding it .
The only documentation they say is it use the protocol https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/src/lib-dict/dict-client.h

I understand it is a simple  script , but if some one wrote such python script or socket program , it will be good to know   where to find those  documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a python server using the socketserver class To read data from the socket and process it.